# Why Google PlacePicker pickPlace crashes on EXC_BREAKPOINT Swift3 IOS10

Tags: ios, google-places-api, swift3

I upgraded XCode to version 8.0 and started to convert my project to Swift3. I use via PODS Google libraries like GoogleMaps, GooglePlaces and GooglePlacePicker. Just like you would guess, everything worked like a charm before update. After update there was hundreds of fix-items to be solved, nothing special here, I managed to solve them, atlas for now.

Basic platform in project is IOS 10.

Problem is that GooglePlacePicker just stopped working and I just cant figure out what is problem. I run it on the Iphone 6 device. PickerView does not ever show up and after a short timeout program crashes and points to the callback function. It does not matter what you have inside the callback function. Anyone has any clues?

See the break point here

[image]

My code:

```
    let center = place.coordinate
    let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + 0.001, center.longitude + 0.001)
    let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - 0.001, center.longitude - 0.001)
    let viewport = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)
    let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: viewport)
    placePicker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)


    placePicker?.pickPlace(callback: { (place: GMSPlace?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if let error = error {
            print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if let place = place {
            print("Place name \(place.name)")
            print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
            print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
        } else {
            print("No place selected")
        }
    } as! GMSPlaceResultCallback)
```

If any advices available, would be appreciated. And I dont think its up the API key, because Autocomplete works still.

Answer (score 4):

Change the type of error in (place: GMSPlace?, error: NSError?)

use swift 3 type: Error?

Hopes that works for you

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you very much! I should have been noticed this.

Comment: @TomiNousiainen mark as ANSWER if this is the solution for your problem

Comment: Wow, the NSError > Error helped me in a completely different issue (with same EXC_BREAKPOINT) issue dealing with "CMMotionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates" ... Thanks!!!

Comment: I had a similar occurrence on iOS 8.4 which gave the following error.  I add it here in case it makes it easier for others to find:  "EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100cdd584"